# maven-enforcer-plugin 3.3.0 breaking behavior for scope

Tags: java, maven

When upgrading Spring Boot to 3.1 I got a transitive upgrade of `maven-enforcer-plugin` **3.3.0**, breaking my build. The configuration of scopes for transitive dependencies behaves strangely.

Current configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*:*:*:compile</exclude>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) on project enrollment-server: 
[ERROR] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.BannedDependencies failed with message:
[ERROR] com.example:test:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:3.1.0
[ERROR]       org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.8 <--- banned via the exclude/include list
```

I have noticed, that there is an option `<searchTransitive>false</searchTransitive>` but it seems to me, that it ignores transitive dependencies completely. So the dependency is not checked but is attached. IMHO the main goal of this plugin was to control the content of the final artifact.

Downgrading to `maven-enforcer-plugin` **3.1.0** so far.

Full example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <!--  Overriding scope of transitive dependency from spring-boot-starter-validation but new enforcer plugin does NOT respect that  -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--  Working with 3.1.0 -->
                <!--  <version>3.1.0</version> -->
                <!--  Implicit version 3.3.0 breaks the build  -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <bannedDependencies>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*:*:*:compile</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </bannedDependencies>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you could create an full example project because there seemed to be a configuration which is not given in your post...

Comment: @khmarbaise The full example was added to the question.

Comment: @banterCZ did I understand properly that the main idea is following: setting `<scope>test</scope>` for `<artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>` cause `maven` to enforce `test` scope for transitive dependencies (there is related issue in maven's jira), you expect that since maven (mistakenly?) enforces `test` scope for `tomcat-embed-el`, `maven-enforcer-plugin` should follow the same logic. Is it correct?

Comment: I already wrote . you have blocked the dependencies in your enforcer rule which denies dependencies in compile scope... but you keep the definition of the dependencies in the compile scope... Based on the enforcer rule you have to change the scope if you don't change it will continue to fail...apart from that I don't understand why you are trying to deny the dependency to tomcat.embed in a spring boot project... if you require reactive you should change to the appropriate reactive components.

Comment: Furthermore you have to exclude the appropriate dependencies via pom (because it's coming into your tree via `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:3.1.0`...)...Check my updated answer...

Comment: The reason why I exclude tomcat-embed is that I prepare a build also for application servers. I changed the scoped to test, which used to work for the older enforcer-plugin. I know I may use exclusion, but it means declaring it at each possible dependency. Anyway, the dependencyManagement fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov May you please link the jira issues? This is not maven misbehavior, but expected work with scopes. I suspect the enforcer-plugin from misevaluation that.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6058 - and a lot of outgoing links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First maven-enforcer-plugin with the given rule is exactly doing what it should be doing means breaking the build based on the given dependencies which are not allowed based on the rules... tried both version exactly the same behaviour ... only the output looks a bit different...

Using the maven-enforcer-plugin version 3.1.0 produces the same failure like this:

```
[INFO] -----------------< com.soebes.spring.example:employee >-----------------
[INFO] Building Employee Demo Application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ employee ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.1.0:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) @ employee ---
[ERROR] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.8
Found Banned Dependency: org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.8
Found Banned Dependency: org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.8
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.447 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-12T12:53:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.1.0:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) on project employee: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```

As the maven-enforcer-plugin version 3.3.0  does:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ employee ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) @ employee ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.405 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-12T12:55:35+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) on project employee: 
[ERROR] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.BannedDependencies failed with message:
[ERROR] com.soebes.spring.example:employee:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.1.0
[ERROR]       org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.1.0
[ERROR]          org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.8 <--- banned via the exclude/include list
[ERROR]          org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.8 <--- banned via the exclude/include list
[ERROR]          org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.8 <--- banned via the exclude/include list
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Update:

If you exclude the tomcat dependency via:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But you must be careful because you need something else which supports servlet etc.

If you need to overwrite the sope of dependency (which means change the scope) you have to do that in a dependencyManagement section...

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <!--  Overriding scope of transitive dependency from spring-boot-starter-validation but new enforcer plugin does NOT respect that  -->
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

That needed to done with each dependency you want to change the scope for...

Comment: I have edited the question and added a full pom example to reproduce.

Comment: I know I may use exclusion, but it means declaring it at each possible dependency. Anyway, the dependencyManagement fixed it (even for Spring Boot as a parent, not import), thanks.

Comment: I still suspect the enforcer-plugin from misevaluation.

Comment: Just try to print out the effective pom file and you will see the difference...

Comment: "but new enforcer plugin does NOT respect that" - isn't that still an issue with the new version of the enforcer plugin...?